# Is the plane in Die Hard 2 a prop?

Tags: props, die-hard-2

In Die Hard 2, Esperanza takes control of the aircraft bringing him into the US to face justice, and then manages to land it.

I cannot identify this plane. Does anyone know if this is a real plane, or a prop created for the movie?

Comment: I can't flag this properly, but this definitely belongs on aviation.stackexchange.com. Post it there, with a picture.

Comment: This is textbook definition trivia that is completely unrelated to the movie itself, and should be closed as such.

Comment: The plane you see depicted on screen does not actually exist--it is a giant prop comprising elements of different aircraft. With that in mind, I posted an answer since the folks at aviation stack exchange would likely be as baffled by what they're seeing as the asker. This actually is a movie-related question.

Comment: @ruffdove ... it might just be me but it it feels a little odd that you've edited a question to change what its asking and then answered it.  The question did not originally ask whether it was real or a prop - it just asked to identify the plane.

Comment: Fair enough. I was trying to make it a movie question instead of an aviation question. I feel like how they did the mock-up is a legit movie question and my answer does in fact answer the original question. I actually answered this a while ago and was looking through old answers when I saw it was closed. Want I should undo the edits?

Answer (score 1):

The plane is a prop created for the movie. It is a non-operational mockup using the fuselage of a [C-123 with significant visual modifications](https://www.impdb.org/index.php?title=Die_Hard_2#Fairchild_C-123_Provider_.28heavily_modified.29). The modifications are such that the plane on screen does not really look like any production aircraft, which is probably why you couldn't identify it. A real C-123 has two propellor engines, [not four jet engines](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099423/goofs). Basically it was a giant prop for the movie, a propellor plane mocked up to look like a military transport jet. When you see the aircraft actually fly, you're looking at a model and CGI.